# Why does jQuery File Upload need reinitializing when using it with KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, knockout.js

I have a file upload component which is bound through a template to a view model (`UploadViewModel`). The file upload dialog is initialized through a custom Knockout binding (`uploadFileDialog`). The UploadViewModel is created when the user clicks the 'Choose file...' button and when the user has selected a file to upload the `fileuploadadd` event should trigger which should invoke `fileSelected` method and then the Start button should be visible as a result. This doesn't seem to happen. The only way to make it work is to re-initialize the file upload dialog every time (the commented code in the `uploadSelectFile` method).
Why does it need to be re-initialized?
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/FKYwB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event is never fired.

Actually, you are not binding to the right element.

Your `uploadFileDialog` should be on the `form` tag in the template like this:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      data-bind="uploadFileDialog: { maxFileSize: 500000000, autoUpload: false },
                 event: { fileuploadadd: fileSelected}">
<!-- -->
</form>
```

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/FKYwB/1/)